# disable convert font style, header, image

Tags: javascript, markdown, showdown

How to only allow change line and link, auto link. disable all other features with showdown https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown  ?
(like font style, header, list style, image ...)
I saw there is subParsers folder, is there a way to use that, I can choose to parse what I want, like

```
var html = showdown.subParser('autoLink');
html = showdown.subParser('..')
 ...
```

js

```
var showdown  = require('showdown');

var converter = new showdown.Converter();
converter.setOption('noHeaderId', true);
converter.setOption('ghCodeBlocks', false);
converter.setOption('literalMidWordUnderscores', true);


var html = converter.makeHtml(d);
console.log(html)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60bjuob8/4/

```
showdown.extension('myext', function() {
  return [{ type: 'lang', regex: /^#/gm, replace: '\\#' }];
});

$('.convert').on('click', function() {
  var cnv = new showdown.Converter({extensions: ['myext']});
  var txt = $('#foo').val();
  var html = cnv.makeHtml(txt);
  $('#bar').val(html);
});
```

Comment: You mention both "Showdown" and "Marked" in your question. They are separate Markdown implementations. Which one are you asking about? The wording of the question suggests Marked but the example uses (and the link points to) Showdown. Are you asking how to do in Marked what you already know how to do in Showdown?

Comment: sorry for my typo, I want to ask Showdown here